# How to make new and old logs?

Tags: mysql, database-design

I have implemented a system in which unauthorized login attempts are stored as data in a database. Also, I have an interface that reviews these unauthorized login attempts. I would like to create a system in which when a user logs in to immediately throw out a message that he has new unauthorized login attempts. I need some system who knows are log old or new.

Comment: I assume you only want to get feedback of new failed login attempts when you login to the interface?
There are several ways to do so. You might use timestamps on the login attempts to check against your latest login and display all those which are newer. Or you can use a flag on the attempts to mark which one has been displayed.

Comment: @dk1 please add it as an answer

Answer (score 1):

You add a flag, `true` or `false`, to each unauthorized login attempts in your database. By default this flag is `false`. When an unauthorized login attempts has been reported to the user you flip the flag(s) to `true`. Next time you only report unauthorized login attempts with a `false` flag.